# Is it possible to specify an event category for Windows EventLogs in code?

Tags: c#, event-log, eventlog-source

I am looking for a way not to use [Message Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363669(v=vs.85).aspx), as I don't want the [mess](http://www.drdobbs.com/customizing-event-log-categories/184405714) that comes with it.

I would like to be able to write events using a method similar to

```
public void WriteEvent(EventLogEntryType type, string description, int eventId, int categoryId)
```

And specify those categories in the same class I register my EventSource, in some enum.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

Even thought things have changed a bit in terms of API, since that blog post I mentioned, yet the principe stayed the same.
See the documentation + samples:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650k61tw(v=vs.100).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventinstance.categoryid(v=vs.100).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventloginstaller.categoryresourcefile(v=vs.100).aspx

I found an acceptable workaround for this; use a different source id, instead of categoryId. It is simpler and can be done with simple API.

Example:
Manage event sources on your own, create event sources per category type. Use some lazy creation logic, e.g by running

```
if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sourceName))
{
    lock (_eventSourceCreationLock)
    {
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sourceName))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(sourceName, _logName);
        }
    }
}
```

And then, use this to write each log entry per source:

```
EventLog.WriteEntry(sourceName, description, type, id);
```

These samples are thread safe as well, as the static calls create a new internal event log.

Instance methods of EventLog aren't guaranteed to be thread safe.